Confusion about area bounded by function
A question from a test exam that goes: "$V$ is the area that is enclosed by the x-axis, y-axis, the horizontal line $y=1$, and the graph of $f(x) = 3\cdot\ln(x)$."
"Caclulate the exact volume of the shape that arises from a solid of revolution around the y-axis."
Now my question is, which of these areas is it?
Desmos visualization
Is it area 3, area 2 or area 1 and 2 combined?
You can ignore the $ln(x)^3$ graph. It was part of another question. The $3\pi/2$ thing is the volume of that shape (picked from the answer sheet)

It's areas A1 and A2 combined. What is A3 doing there? It doesn't even touch the $y$-axis!

@AnotherUser Thank you for taking the time to answer. I appreciate it. But in this case, A3 could still go around the y-axis, no? You'd just have the area between x=1 and x=e^1/3 and y=0 and y=1. Like a donut.

Yes, it can go around the $y$-axis. So what? That is irrelevant to the description of the region that you are interested in, which is "the area that is enclosed by the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, the horizontal line $y=1$, and the graph of $f(x)=3\cdot\ln(x)$." And, again, A3 doesn't even touch the $y$-axis.

@AnotherUser forgive me, but I don't understand the relevance of it touching the y-axis. Is this because then the volume is infinite?

Because, by the definition of the region, it is bounded by the $y$-axis. Please keep in mind that determining the region is independent of the computation of the volume.

It is areas 1 and 2 combined. Area 3 is completely irrelevant in this case as it is outside the area that is bounded by the x- and y-axis, $y=1$, and $f(x)=3\ln(x)$.
I suggest opening a new tab and entering only the expressions related to the problem at hand, helps clear confusion in most cases.
